DateTimeFormat Hindi does not have lunar month option
Using Intl.DateTimeFormat() as shown below:
const fullHindi = {
    weekday: 'long',
    dayPeriod: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'short',
    day: 'numeric',
    dayPeriod: "narrow",
    hour: '2-digit',
    minute: '2-digit',
    second: 'numeric',
    calendar: 'indian',
    timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
    numberingSystem: 'deva',
    formatMatcher: 'basic',
    hourCycle: 'h24',
};
const samay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("hi", fullHindi);
const today = new Date();
const hindi = samay.format(today);
console.log({hindi}); // शक मंगलवार, २२ श्रावण १९४६, २३:४४:०८

but it's not correct though its Shuka/Saptami शुक्ल सप्तमी
In a nutshell, the lunar calendar which have 15 days and paksha so requirement is that it changes to different paksha ( either Shukla/Krishna ) see more details here
My question: is there any format or style option configuration is there which change this; similar to h12 and h24 format for time change ot to AM PM

what is script tag for sasnkrit? can we use "hi_sa" ; that might change date into hindi

I Think this is the output you expect


const pakshaNames = {
  'Shukla': 'शुक्ला',
  'Krishna': 'कृष्ण'
};

const tithiNames = [
  'प्रथमा', 'द्वितीया', 'तृतीया', 'चतुर्थी', 'पञ्चमी', 'षष्ठी', 'सप्तमी', 'अष्टमी',
  'नवमी', 'दशमी', 'एकादशी', 'द्वादशी', 'त्रयोदशी', 'चतुर्दशी', 'पञ्चमी', 'षष्ठी',
  'सप्तमी', 'अष्टमी', 'नवमी', 'दशमी', 'एकादशी', 'द्वादशी', 'त्रयोदशी', 'चतुर्दशी',
  'पञ्चमी', 'षष्ठी', 'सप्तमी', 'अष्टमी', 'नवमी', 'दशमी', 'एकादशी', 'द्वादशी',
  'त्रयोदशी', 'चतुर्दशी', 'पञ्चमी', 'षष्ठी', 'सप्तमी', 'अष्टमी', 'नवमी', 'दशमी'
];

const getPaksha = (date) => {
  const day = date.getDate();
  return day <= 15 ? 'Shukla' : 'Krishna';
};

const getTithi = (date) => {
  const day = date.getDate() - 1; // Zero-based index for tithi names array
  return `Tithi ${tithiNames[day] || 'Unknown'}`;
};

const getHinduMonthAndYear = (date) => {
  const months = [
    'Chaitra', 'Vaishakha', 'Jyeshtha', 'Ashadha', 'Shravana', 'Bhadrapada',
    'Ashvin', 'Kartika', 'Margashirsha', 'Pushya', 'Magha', 'Phalguna'
  ];
  const monthIndex = (date.getMonth() + 1 + 1) % 12; // Example adjustment for month index
  const hinduYear = date.getFullYear() - 1000; // Example offset, adjust as needed
  
  return { month: months[monthIndex], year: hinduYear };
};

const formatHinduDate = (date) => {
  const paksha = pakshaNames[getPaksha(date)];
  const tithi = getTithi(date);
  const { month, year } = getHinduMonthAndYear(date);
  
  return `${paksha} Paksha, ${tithi}, ${month}, ${year}`;
};

const today = new Date();
const formattedDate = formatHinduDate(today);
console.log(formattedDate);




Thanks but I am looking for some options in DateFormat

month name already coming in my question. Only issue with tithi ( in sanskrit like चतुर्थी) and paksha

I have made some changes in code please check the output  now. DateFormat you means moment and date-fns?

I am not asking how to convert the date but inbuilt config



function getPaksha(date) {
    const day = date.getDate();
    if (day <= 15) {
        return "शुक्ल";
    } else {
        return "कृष्ण";
    }
}

function formatDateWithPaksha(date) {
    const paksha = getPaksha(date);

    const fullHindi = {
        weekday: 'long',
        year: 'numeric',
        month: 'short',
        day: 'numeric',
        hour: '2-digit',
        minute: '2-digit',
        second: 'numeric',
        calendar: 'indian',
        timeZone: 'Asia/Kolkata',
        numberingSystem: 'deva',
        hourCycle: 'h24',
    };

    const samay = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("hi-IN", fullHindi);
    const formattedDate = samay.format(date);

    return `${paksha} पक्ष, ${formattedDate}`;
}

const today = new Date();
const hindiDateWithPaksha = formatDateWithPaksha(today);
console.log({ hindiDateWithPaksha });



Uses Intl.DateTimeFormat to format the date in Hindi, including weekday, year, month, day, and time.
Adds the Paksha (from getPaksha) to the formatted date string.
The current date is formatted and displayed with the Paksha included.

date.getDate() does not take the correct timezone into account

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
